# Compute integral in probability task.

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory

Let's consider $X,Y$ are i.r.v. with $N(0,1)$ distribution. Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. We want to know distribution of $Z = (X-a)^{2} + (Y-b)^{2}$.

My attempt : let $\bar{X} = X-a$ and $\bar{Y} = Y-b$, then $\displaystyle \mathbb{P}(Z\le z) = \int_{\bar{X}^{2} + \bar{Y}^{2} \le z}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left((\bar{X}+a)^{2} +(\bar{Y}+b)^2)\right)}dxdy$. 
I've made a polar substitution, but then stuck with something like $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-r(a\cos\phi + b \sin \phi)}$.

So maybe there is easier approach to solve it , or to compute this integral?

Comment: Is it assumed that the two random variables are independent?

Comment: @callculus yes, they are independent

Answer (score 0):

Your $Z$ is distributed as a noncentral chi-squared distribution. Information about the distribution can be found here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution

Unfortunately I doubt you can simplify the integral for the CDF much analytically.